# VLC WebPlugin blocks websocket while playing

Tags: c#, javascript, plugins, websocket, vlc

I have simple html/js application with embedded VLC WebPlugin and few methods for play/pause. This application is controlled by another javascript file through simple server/websocket c# application. Topology is like this:

```
WebpageWithVLCplugin <= ws://localhost:8181 => C#Server <= http://localhost:8080 => WebpageWithControl
```

Everything works fine - sending controls from Control page through C#Server is fast and reliable even through different domains, but when I send "play" command - VLC plugin starts to play video - no more commads are received by page with "WebpageWithVLCplugin" until playing is finished. So it seems that VLC WebPlugin blocks websocket - but I dont have any idea how or why or how should I find problem.

edit: When WebpageWithVLCplugin is controlled not through websockets (window.postMessage or direct methods call), everything works fine even while VLC plugin is playing.

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found my silly mistake - Simple server is even file-provider for VLC player, so when VLC player starts to play, server is busy with providing video file. When multi-threaded, everythink works fine.